# Calculation in CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008, I'm trying to do some calculation inside the case when statement.

I have a problem in the last column [PM], any other suggestion to do calculation inside case when with the date parameter : `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` ?

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '1/1/2019'
DECLARE @EndDate date = '4/30/2019'
DECLARE @StartDatePreviousYear date = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @StartDate)
DECLARE @EndDatePreviousYear date = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @EndDate)

SELECT
     DATENAME(month, [GL_DATEPIECE]) AS [MONTH]
    ,[et_region] AS [REGION]
    ,[e].[et_etablissement] AS [STORE CODE]
    ,[et_libelle] AS [STORE NAME]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN [GP_DATEPIECE] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate THEN ISNULL([gl_totalttcdev], 0) ELSE 0 END) AS [CA]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN [GP_DATEPIECE] BETWEEN @StartDatePreviousYear AND @EndDatePreviousYear THEN ISNULL([gl_totalttcdev], 0) ELSE 0 END) AS [CA_AN],
(CASE WHEN [GP_DATEPIECE] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate THEN ISNULL(sum(gl_totalttcdev)/count(distinct(GL_NUMERO)), 0) ELSE 0 END) AS [PM]

FROM [piece]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [etabliss] AS [e] ON [piece].[gp_etablissement] = [e].[et_etablissement]
GROUP BY
     DATENAME(month, [GL_DATEPIECE])
    ,[et_region]
    ,[et_etablissement]
    ,[et_libelle]
ORDER BY
     [et_region] ASC
    ,[et_etablissement] ASC
```

Comment: And what problem do you have with that calculation ?

Comment: My guess is integer division. In integers `9/10 = 0`. Impossible to tell without knowing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'case' should be correct if your GP_DATEPIECE column are a datetime. But you can't divide by zero, dont forget it.

Try Something like this :

```
CASE 
WHEN count(distinct(GL_NUMERO)=0 then 0
WHEN [GP_DATEPIECE] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate THEN ISNULL(sum(gl_totalttcdev)/count(distinct(GL_NUMERO)), 0) ELSE 0 
END AS [PM]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `NULLIF`

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '1/1/2019'
DECLARE @EndDate date = '4/30/2019'
DECLARE @StartDatePreviousYear date = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @StartDate)
DECLARE @EndDatePreviousYear date = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @EndDate)

SELECT
     DATENAME(month, [GL_DATEPIECE]) AS [MONTH]
    ,[et_region] AS [REGION]
    ,[e].[et_etablissement] AS [STORE CODE]
    ,[et_libelle] AS [STORE NAME]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN [GP_DATEPIECE] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate THEN ISNULL([gl_totalttcdev], 0) ELSE 0 END) AS [CA]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN [GP_DATEPIECE] BETWEEN @StartDatePreviousYear AND @EndDatePreviousYear THEN ISNULL([gl_totalttcdev], 0) ELSE 0 END) AS [CA_AN],
(CASE WHEN [GP_DATEPIECE] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate THEN ISNULL(sum(gl_totalttcdev)/NULLIF(count(distinct(GL_NUMERO)),0), 0) ELSE 0 END) AS [PM]

FROM [piece]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [etabliss] AS [e] ON [piece].[gp_etablissement] = [e].[et_etablissement]
GROUP BY
     DATENAME(month, [GL_DATEPIECE])
    ,[et_region]
    ,[et_etablissement]
    ,[et_libelle]
ORDER BY
     [et_region] ASC
    ,[et_etablissement] ASC
```